# multiple interdependent javascript files in one html file

Tags: javascript, html, dependency-management

I have two javascript files (file1, file2). File1 uses a class defined in file2. Am I able to reference these files from an html file the following manner:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="file1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="file2.js"></script>
```

Will this allow for file1's dependence upon the class defined in file2?
If not what are some plugins that do allow for this sort of dependency?

Comment: Why don't you include file2.js first?

Comment: Sounds like you need to check out RequireJS

Comment: If file1 needs file2, then shouldn't the order of the script tags be reversed? Apart from that, I'm a fan of requirejs too, but it might be overkill if you just have these 2 files.

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with the way you are going to use them. A simplified approach.

**Scenario 1:**

*script1.js*

```
function primary()
{
    secondary();
}
```

*script2.js*

```
function secondary()
{
    alert("hi primary");
}
```

*test.html*

```
<html>
<head>
<script src=script1.js></script>
<script src=script2.js></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

It works (you already know it)

**Scenario 2:**

*script1.js*

```
secondary();
```

*script2.js and test.html as above*

It's not working (js error)

**Scenario 3:**

*script1.js*

```
secondary();
```

*script2.js remains the same*

*test.html*

```
<html>
<head>
<script src=script1.js defer></script>
<script src=script2.js></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

It works.

Is this what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Overview:

Use Jquery to load JS dynamically using the following:

```
$.getScript("file1.js",function(){

    alert("File1.js is loaded");
}
```

Example with Object Oriented JS and dynamic js loading.

File1.js as:

```
File1 = function(){
}
File1.prototype=
{
    constructor:File1,
    primary:function()
    {
        if (File2 == "undefined")
        {
           $.getScript("file2.js",function()
           {
              file2 = new File2();
              file2.secondary();
           });
        }
    }
}
```

File2.js As:

```
File2 = function(){
}
File2.prototype=
{
  constructor:File2,
  secondary:function()
  {
    if (File1 == "undefined")
    {
      $.getScript("file1.js",functiom()
      {
         file1 = new File1();
         file1.primary();
      });
    }
  }
}
```

This should give you pretty good idea of dynamic loading of JS, and JS Object oriented concept as well.